# Typescript typegoose getModelForClass return type

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

Using `typegoose`/`mongoose` I can get the Model for a Class like this (where `Clip` is some class that will be saved to db)

```
import { getModelForClass } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
...

const ClipModel = getModelForClass(Clip);
```

And this Model is constructible, by this I mean I can do this;

```
const clip = new ClipModel()
const clip = new ClipModel({someProp: "someValue"})
```

#### Questions

1. How is this possible. If I look at the return type of `getModelForClass` here it is `ReturnModelType<U, QueryHelpers>` so how can a type have a constructor? Is this not the same as doing;

```
const clip = new ReturnModelType<Clip, QueryHelpers>(); // Ts error: 'ReturnModelType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

2. IF ClipModel can be constructed does this mean that ClipModel is a class? If it is it should be possible to do this right?

```
class MyCustomModel extends ClipModel {
 // Add some customisations 
}
```

However, this give a ts error `Base constructors must all have the same return type.`

3. Is it possible to extend ClipModel to have some custom functions on it so it can be called like;

```
ClipModel.find({}) // the default created find method 
ClipModel.myCustomFind({}) // find method with custom stuff
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to extend ClipModel to have some custom functions on it so it can be called like;

what you are searching for are [static methods](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/quick-start-guide/#static-methods)

> IF ClipModel can be constructed does this mean that ClipModel is a class? If it is it should be possible to do this right?

`ClipModel` (what gets returned in runtime from `getModelForClass`) is a instance of `mongoose.Model`, and in JS a instance cannot be extended from

> How is this possible. If I look at the return type of getModelForClass here it is ReturnModelType<U, QueryHelpers> so how can a type have a constructor? Is this not the same as doing;

you can read more in the documentation about [`ReturnModelType`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/types/return-model-type/)

also your example is weird, a type cannot be used at runtime, what would be correct would be:

```js
type TCustomModel = ReturnModelType<typeof Class>;
// and if you have QueryHelpers for the Class
type TCustomModel = ReturnModelType<typeof Class, ClassQueryHelpers>

// and then later
const CustomModel: TCustomModel = getModelForClass(Class);
// or (pseudo code, may need more more types in ".model<>")
const CustomModel: TCustomModel = mongoose.model('Name', schema);
```

read more about `QueryHelpers` in [`@queryMethod`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/query-method)